# foo instanceof Date などの式の構造について

Tags: javascript

Objectの型を調べる時には`foo instanceof Date`というような方法を使う事を先程知りました。

このように3つの要素を並べる書き方に馴染みがないのですが、同様の書き方をする処理はjavascriptには他にもあるのでしょうか？

それともこの書き方は何らかの糖衣構文なのでしょうか？

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`instanceof`は二項演算子ですので特殊な構文というわけではありません。右辺(質問の`Date`)は特別なキーワードというわけではなく、コンストラクター一般が指定できます。

JavaScriptで定義されているアルファベットの二項演算子は他には`in`があります。

Comment: なるほど`=`や`+`などと同じ扱いなのですね。ありがとうございます。